# Affinity issue on GCP with multiple zones

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We have a kubernetes job based application which spins up pods equal to the number of nodes in the cluster(using completions). The job needs to run once on each of the nodes to calculate certain node metrics. We have podAntiAffinity configuration set to ensure this, so each pod runs on a separate node and does the job. Also, we use an RWO storage in our application. Now, on a GCP cluster with 2 zones, we observed that by default the persistent-volume created is getting associated to one of the 2 zones

```
kubectl describe pv pvc-xxxxxx
Name:              pvc-xxxxxxx
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
                   volume.kubernetes.io/provisioner-deletion-secret-name:
                   volume.kubernetes.io/provisioner-deletion-secret-namespace:
Finalizers:        [kubernetes.io/pv-protection external-attacher/pd-csi-storage-gke-io]
StorageClass:      xxxxxx
Status:            Bound
Claim:             xxxxxxxx
Reclaim Policy:    Delete
Access Modes:      RWO
VolumeMode:        Filesystem
Capacity:          50Gi
**Node Affinity:
  Required Terms:
    Term 0:        topology.gke.io/zone in [asia-south1-a]**
Message:
```

Due to this node affinity as shown above to one zone, all pods are getting attached to nodes of asia-south1-a zone only and the pods are not running on nodes of other zone.

So my question is, how can I make sure that in this case, pods run on nodes of both regions?

If we modify the storageClass to include "**allowedTopologies**" and add both zones there, or if we use "**replication-type: regional-pd**" our use-case is working fine, but we do not want to use this as our app may have to run on environments where these are not set.

My understanding is if we use a Statefulset with volumeClaimTemplate, each pod will have its own pvc and then GCP may split the pv's between both the zones? But our usecase cannot use statefulset and needs to use jobs... SO is there any specific setting we can use in jobs to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

I tried to create 2 pvc's and split the pods equally such that half use pvc-1 and other half use pvc-2 and expected GCP to associate both pvc's to different zones, but that is not happening. Both are getting attached to same zone.

Comment: Does your storage class have `waitForConsumer` set to `true`?

Comment: @GariSingh yes it does